# How can I attach the Chrome/Edge DevTools node inspector to node?

Tags: node.js, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, microsoft-edge

I am attempting to both the node inspector in Chrome DevTools `chrome://inspect` and Edge DevTools `edge://inspect`

Node is running with the `--inspect-brk` option.

[image]

Node says:

```
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/c6149f1f-e0cf-4d7e-8cfb-11cffaaf34ad
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
```

**How do I know if the inspector is attached to node?** The option to take a snapshot is greyed out, typing `console.log('hello')` doesn't do anything in the terminal where node is running. This makes it seem like I am not attached. But I can't see from the UI. Do I have to click something? What do I have to click? **How can I attach the inspector to node?**

Comment: Which version of Chrome and Edge are you using? I test according to [this article](https://flaviocopes.com/node-debug-devtools/) and the node inspector works. The process is like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Chck.gif. We need to wait the **Remote Target** to show then the buttons and console will work then the inspector will be attached to node.